# html form with differnet language texts

Tags: html, forms, servlets, submission, tamil

I want to get tamil language input text values in server side.
wt I did was

```
<style type="text/css">
        @font-face {
            font-family: FontFamilyName;
            font-weight: bold;
            src: url('TAMIL.TTF');
        }

        .tamil {
            font-family:"FontFamilyName"; 
        }
```

- added in the header.

and this HTML form

```
   <form action="aa" >
                <input type="text" class="tamil" name="ss">
                <input type="submit" value="ss">
    </form>
```

when typing it takes tamil texts which is I want but when take those values in the server side its converting to english letters.

Hw can I solve this issue.
thanks :)

Comment: What server side language are you using, or why do you want to perform this operation using server side code? This can be done in JavaScript by determining the UNICODE equivalents of the Tamil characters, and then translating the Unicode into their corresponding English counterparts. However, before providing a solution, I'd like to get some more information from you.

Comment: I am using PHP for server side, please ask me if u want more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your html files' text encoding, and make sure your server supports tamil。
maybe you should convert everything to utf-8~
best wishes~

Comment: yes, but I need specifically for that input text field, because I have different text fields in english with the same page,